# Jenkins file execution error while running shell commands

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, sed

The below code is being used to trigger a shell command using Jenkins file.

```
sh """
     val=\$(echo ${val} | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g')
     echo ${val}
   """
```

The below error reflects as part of the code :

**/home/me/@tmp/abcd/script.sh: command substitution: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('**

Any solution to the same ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have escaped `$` in line of `sed` but you have NOT done the same in `echo` line try escaping it once by doing `echo \${val}`?

Comment: It's giving the error in the line prior to that. Also i tried escaping the 2nd line but it didn't work